# ServiceStack.Razor output absolute URL from razor view

Tags: c#, razor, servicestack

Having a play around https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars, like it a lot. Just wondering if anyone could help me find a way to output absolute URLs from a view when using the self-hosted application?

This is as good as I can come up with:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string AbsoluteContent(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string path)
    {
        var baseUri = new Uri(EndpointHost.AppHost.Config.WebHostUrl);
        return new Uri(baseUri, path).ToString();
    }
}
```

Where AppHost.Config.WebHostUrl is set by me when the host is configured

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I should have been clearer, I am actually using ServiceStack in a slightly non standard way - as a means to render email templates. So I have a service such as:

```
public class EmailService : Service
{
    public void Post(EmailTask request)
    {
        var format = GetAppHost().Plugins.Find(x => x is RazorFormat) as RazorFormat;
        var template = format.ExecuteTemplate(request.Model,   request.Template.ToString(), string.Empty);
        var html = template.Result;
        // email the rendered template etc
    }
}
```

When the template is rendered, the Request object is null

Answer (score 1):

In the Razor [ViewPageBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor/ViewPageBase.cs) you have access to the HTTP `base.Request` and `base.Response` where you can access metadata about the request like `base.Request.AbsoluteUri` which returns the current Request Url which should contain the info you want.

Comment: This is not a use-case we're supporting. But should be obvious why `Request` is null. I suggest you pass the Url into your Model if you're going to use it offline like this. Also please don't leave out critical info like this from future Q's as it unnecessarily wastes answerers time.